# Proof of a property of set of all one-to-one mappings

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a nonempty set and $A(S)$ be the set of all one-to-one mappings of $S$ onto itself. I.N. Herstein in *Topics in Algebra* says (in page 28) that whenever $S$ has three or more elements, we can find two elements $\alpha,\beta\in A(S)$ such that $\alpha \circ \beta \neq \beta \circ \alpha$.

Why is this true? Suppose we assume on the contrary that for every $\alpha,\beta\in A(S)$, we have $\alpha \circ \beta = \beta \circ \alpha$, how do we obtain a contradiction to this assumption?

Although https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1058719/114758 gives an example (and hence proof), is there a way to contradict my assumption by not taking an example?

Comment: Consider the set of all permutations that fix all elements of the set, except for three specified elements which may either be fixed or mapped to another of the three. This set of permutations forms a group isomorphic to the symmetric group on three elements, which is non commutative. The result follows.

Comment: @Vik78: this is a nice interpretation, but the usual proof that $S_{3}$ is not commutative is very nearly *exactly* the same as actually exhibiting the maps on $3$ elements which don't commute (up to relabling, of course). That said, I don't think there's really a great way to answer this; proving that $S_{3}$ is nonabelian by other means seems silly to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do what you are saying, but based on your demand, the proof is slightly more lengthy, and involves more terminology than you would like.

So we know that the set of one-to-one mappings from $S$ to itself, form a group under composition. Note that this group is abelian, because of our assumption. Further, the order of this group is $3!=6$.

So it is known that our group is abelian. Consider the conjugacy classes of the elements of $S_3$. By considering the cycle type, you see that these are in bijection with the partitions of $n$. It is known that an element is in the center if and only if it's conjugacy class has only one element. That way we would be expecting $6$ conjugacy classes if the group were abelian, because then the center would be the whole group, however the number of partitions of $3$ is $4$, because $3=3=2+1=1+2=1+1+1$, so there are four representations. This is a proof, without exhibition of an example, that $S_3$ is non-abelian. For $S_n$, find yourself a way of proving that $p(n)<n!$ (it's easy actually) so that $S_n$ will also be non-abelian.

An even stronger theorem is that the center of $S_n$ is trivial, that is to say, other than the identity, **no other bijection commutes with all other bijections**.

So this is a proof the way you like it, albeit technical. Please ask if you have further doubts or would like me to explain the cyclic decomposition.

Comment: I did not expect so much terminology! Since this property is discussed early on in the text book, I assumed the proof would be elementary. I need to study a few more concepts before I can understand your answer. If any doubts persist, I shall ask.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\sigma_1 = (1 \ 2 \ 3), \sigma_2 = (1\  2)$ then
$\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2 = (1 \ 3)$ and  $\sigma_2 \circ \sigma_1 = (2 \ 3)$.

Now use this to generate a contradiction.

Comment: This answer gives an explicit counterexample, which is exactly what the OP mentioned they did not want.

Comment: The OP also asked for a way to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. The OP asked for a means of obtaining a contradiction that *does not involve taking an example*, and this answer does just that - am I missing something? Regardless, you're obviously free to leave this answer as you see fit...

Comment: @copper.hat I'm aware of that counterexample. I just wanted to know if there was a way to contradict my assumption based purely on theory without involving a counter example, as Alex Wertheim said.

Comment: @ArpithaPrasad: Well, it is not satisfactory, but the above example shows that as long as $S$ has three of more elements then there is a non commuting pair, hence if all elements commute then $S$ must have less than three elements, hence a contradiction.